# Java 8: How to get element at an index from a Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream, I need to get the element at an index in this stream
Basically, a fetch on the basis of index of element like in List
`list.get(index)`

Comment: `skip(index).findFirst()`…

Comment: Although Holger is correct, do you really want to **discard** all other elements of the stream?

Comment: @Holger thank you, it worked :)

Comment: if you have a Stream that is not ordered (let's say the source is a `Set`) what would this index mean at all?

Comment: @Andreas No, I don't want to discard the elements

Comment: @Eugene It's a stream of an ordered collection :)

Comment: @4rpit Then Holger's suggestion will not work for you, because it discards all other elements, and a stream can only be used once, so once that code has executed, the stream cannot be re-processed.

Comment: @Andreas: it *skips* them, which implies being not processed in this specific stream operation, but when the source is a collection, you can stream over it as often as you want. The use case has not been described sufficiently to determine whether it is useful or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a skip method that abandons access to first N elements
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-

After that you can use limit(1) and you have just one element at specified index.

EDIT: After @Holger answer there's also a possibility to call

```
stream().skip(index).findFirst()
```